# using matlab regex to extract data

Tags: regex, matlab

I'm going to extract data of such sentences:

```
<rupture dip="30.0" id="trt=00~ses=0173~src=1~rup=2-01" magnitude="5.25" rake="60.0" strike="322.0" tectonicRegion="Active Shallow Crust">
<rupture dip="60.0" id="trt=00~ses=0532~src=1~rup=1-01" magnitude="4.75" rake="60.0" strike="322.0" tectonicRegion="Active Shallow Crust">
```

The data I need is dip, magnitude, rake and strike.
I tried regexp but couldn't struct it right.

```
k =1;
for i = 1:length(textf)
    if  strcmp(char(textf(i,2:12)),'ruptuer dip')==1 
        x = regexp(textf(i,:), '.*?(\d \w (\.\d+)*)', 'tokens' );
        dip(k,1) = str2double(char(x{1}));
        mag(k,2) = str2double(char(x{2}));
        rake(k,3) = str2double(char(x{3}));
        strike(k,4) = str2double(char(x{4}));
        k=k+1;
    end
end
```

can anybody help me with that.

Comment: Why not use `xmlread`? Regex is possible but usually more difficult and less robust...

Comment: Or `xslt` to convert it to a csv or so... It's an xml document, so it's usually better to use an xml tool set

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis tnx but the problem is I've never used these functions and don't know how

Comment: Can `dip`, `magnitude`, `rake` and `strike` attributes contain integers (like `dip="50"`)?

Comment: @dorukayhan yes they do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this requires more than 2 capturing groups. To be exact, you need 4 captures like the following ([mandatory regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/0rXcQv/2)):

```
<rupture dip="(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)" id="[^"]*" magnitude="(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)" rake="(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)" strike="(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)" tectonicRegion="[^"]*">
```

In each capturing group, `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` matches a number that can be either an integer or a number with a decimal point. In the attributes `id` and `tectonicRegion`, `[^"]*` matches whatever there is between the double quotes (you can replace the asterisk with a plus sign if `id` and/or `tectonicRegion` may not be empty).